# nginx load balancing - keep last working server

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have two servers A and B.
Most of the time, both servers are not running at the same time.

So when A is running, it is most likely that B is not running. 
When B is running, it is most likely that A is not running.
This switch between A and B can happen after some weeks.

So I would like that nginx redirect to the running server and **keep** using that server until it is down.

I have tried that solution:

```
    upstream backend { 
     server SERVER_A; 
     server SERVER_B;
    }
    server {...}
```

This is working but I can see in the logs that it is periodically trying to connect to the "down" server.

Then I tried that:

```
 upstream backend { 
     server SERVER_A; 
     server SERVER_B backup;
    }
    server {...}
```

This is working correctly if SERVER_A is up. But if it is SERVER_B, then it is frequently trying to access SERVER_A. 
Actually, in that case, the correct configuration would be "server SERVER_A backup;" but I don't think we can do dynamic reconfiguration ;-)

Actually, it is not a very big deal that nginx is periodically trying to access the down server, but if I can avoid that using a correct configuration, it would be better.

I know about that fail-timeout argument. But I don't think it will really solve my issue, and it might even add some down time during switching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *This switch between A and B can happen after some weeks.* does that behaviour controlled? Is there any procedure you can hook to mark the other server is down?

Comment: Yes this is controlled via a bash script. If I can somehow inform nginx about the switch, it could even be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to controlled mechanism for server switch a hook to mark an individual server down is only required:

```
sed -i 's/server SERVER_A;/server SERVER_A down;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx -s reload
```

A configuration load of standard procedure that handles graceful reload and it is safe: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control

> Once the master process receives the signal to reload configuration,
>   it checks the syntax validity of the new configuration file and tries
>   to apply the configuration provided in it. If this is a success, the
>   master process starts new worker processes and sends messages to old
>   worker processes, requesting them to shut down. Otherwise, the master
>   process rolls back the changes and continues to work with the old
>   configuration. Old worker processes, receiving a command to shut down,
>   stop accepting new connections and continue to service current
>   requests until all such requests are serviced. After that, the old
>   worker processes exit.

Comment: Thanks ! It is working well. I didn't think about that possibility to do hot replacement of the configuration. To be complete, we must not forget to do sed -i 's/server SERVER_B down;/server SERVER_B;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  as well